# CefSharp crashing when javascript tries to parse an object containing a list sent from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp to have a webbrowser run angularjs code inside a winforms application.

I am able to send c# objects to the js side and then use them if they only contain strings, ints, and so on. But when I try to send an object containing a list of values in it, CefSharp crashes when it trys to parse it on the js side.

An example of the c# code:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string other { get; set; }
    public List<int> ints { get; set; } 
}
```

Working obj:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass()
{
    name = "Bobby Test",
    other = "Hello"
};
```

Obj causing crashes:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass()
{
    name = "Bobby Test",
    other = "Hello",
    ints = new List<int>(){0,1}
};
```

How I pass to the js code:

```
browser.RegisterJsObject("testObj", tc);
```

My angular code setting it up for use:

```
$scope.$watch(function ()
{ return window.testObj },
function () {
    $scope.someField = window.testObj;
});
```

I tried doing a JsonConvert.SerializeObject on the object before passing it but it ended up just being an empty object on the js side.

**EDIT - Solution**

*C# to JS:*

Changed TestClass to:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass()
{
    name = "Bobby Test",
    other = "Hello",
    ints = new int[] {0,1}
};
```

And it works correctly with the code above without having to call any serializing or deserializing methods directly.

*JS to C#:*

Although it wasn't in my question:

I am passing an object to the js side with a callback function to c#, the callback function accepts a serialized string from the js side which I then deserialize on the c# side.

Comment: I know this is old but for anybody having issues w/ passing data from c# a good trick is to base64 encode the data and then decode in javascript w/ `atob(base64Str)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chromium can only handle javascript simple types (Arrays, Numbers, Strings, etc)

What I normally do on the server side with any complex data is return a JSON string:

```
JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);
```

And then on the client side reconstitute it using

```
JSON.parse(myObjectAsString);
```

Works for me

Comment: I was unable to get serializing the c# object containing lists and then deseralizing on the js side to work. The object was always empty after deserialzing it or it crashed cefsharp. I did try switching my Lists to arrays and I can call the browser.RegisterJsObject("testObj", tc); on that and access the object on the js side. Also, your blog was extremely helpful in setting this up initially.